# Не работает редактируемая колонка kartik\grid\EditableColumn, с данными которые приходят ajax запросом

Tags: php, ajax, yii2, gridview, kartik

Есть две таблицы GridView. С первой таблицей, где данные приходят c помощью ajax не работает редактируемая колонка kartik\grid\EditableColumn, Со второй таблицей, где данные приходят без ajax все работает. Что можно сделать, чтобы EditableColumn работал с данными переданными ajax запросом? 
Вот часть кода GridView с полями:

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'id' => 'color-group-grid',
    'columns' => [        

        'id',
        [
            'class' => 'kartik\grid\EditableColumn',
            'attribute' => 'name',
            'editableOptions' => [
                'header' => '<br><b>Название</b>',
            ],
            'value' => function ($model) {
                return $model->name;
            },
        ],
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
        'template' => '{delete}']
    ],
]); ?>
```

Скрипт с ajax запросом:

```
$('#color-group-grid table tbody tr:first').addClass('success');

$(document.body).on('click', '#color-group-grid table tbody tr' , function() 
{
  $('#color-group-grid tbody tr').removeClass('success');
  $(this).addClass('success');

  var id = $(this).closest("tr").attr("data-key");
  $.ajax  ({
           url: urlColorGroupDataKey,
           type: 'GET',
           data: "id="+id,              
           // data: a,
           success: function(rest) {
               console.log(rest);              
               $('#transfer-success').html(rest);
           },
       });

});
```